# server parameter not specified in *.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I get the message:

```
'server' parameter not specified in *.py
```

after doing:

```
appcfg.py update *.py
```

in the terminal. 
When I look in my dashboard at the app the column current version says 'none deployed'.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command from the terminal, you want to point `appcfg.py` to the folder that contains your application files. This folder will be the one that contains your `app.yaml`. Assuming that folder is called `my_project`, you would execute the following from the folder above your application:

```
python appcfg.py update my_project
```

The difference here is that you are supplying your entire application to `appcfg`, as opposed to any `.py` files (which as you see will not work).